# Is there a list of languages which run naively on the Arduino platform

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino at home and am able to write programs in C which compile and run on the Arduino once it is disconnected from my PC.

When it comes to languages like Ruby for example, the PC must be connected at all times in order for it to send commands.

What I'd like is to be able to write programs in languages other than C. Even if it's a transpiled language which goes from B -> C.

Where can I find a listing of supported languages which compile and run naively on Arduino?

### Update

Although not related directly to the question, Xamarin Monkey Robotics allows one to write in any language supported by the .NET runtime and have it cross compiled to run on the Arduino and other devices. https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get a transpiler to compile your high level code to c.

- Python: https://code.google.com/p/py2c/
- Ruby: http://blog.zenspider.com/blog/2005/01/an-introduction-to-ruby2c-automatic-translation-of-ruby-code-to-c.html

Answer (score 0):

The code that runs on the arduino is assembly.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AVR
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/arduino-with-assembly

The reason you code with c is that c can directly be translated into assembly code this is called compiling.

http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/code10.html

notice if you go to -> sketch it has an option for verify/compile

sending commands from a language like ruby or any other for that matter are possible through UART - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter

or  any other communication protocol either over a physical ethernet/ usb cable or wirelessly through bluetooth, wifi, etc.

It should be noted that the communication protocol is in c (assembly) on the arduino itself. so the instruction is basically converting to c through the protocol.

high level languages are nice but highly abstracted from low level 'things' aka hardware which is what the arduino is and what it controls.

check out the arduino website for tutorials or guides

-Chris

Comment: That's not entirely true, assembly doesn't run on the processor, the instructions are simply interpreted by the hardware into a language it executes. There's no reason a high level language can't sit on top of a VM...herd of .NET micro ?:) coffeescript is compiled to JavaScript. Isn't there anything that compiles to C?

Comment: It's simple. Just write your own translator

Comment: No, assembly (or machine code, if you want to get pedantic) is the lowest language. Neither AVR nor ARM uses microcode therefore there is no translation to a lower language.